Change skin in "cloned" minecraft
I have not really cloned my Minecraft, but kinda. On my laptop I run my Minecraft with command file (.bat) instead of the usual launcher, and on my gaming computer I run it as usual. This is so I can play lan between the two. I learnt how to do it with this video.
This works but I want to change the skin on my "cloned" Minecraft. I have tried to check the launch file (.bat) if I can change something so it gets the skin from a different file or something but I couldn't find it.
If you have any questions please write a comment, and thanks for any help.

When you say "skin", do you mean the icon you click on to launch it?

No like the skin in the game

Maybe try to change the username in the .bat file to a username with the specific skin you like, such usernames can be found over on https://namemc.com/

In extremely old versions of Minecraft, this is true, assuming the old skin URLs are still active - But today: Not anymore.

I found some skins that work

You can't.
Because your two players are the same account, they share the same access token. As a result the two players share the same skin.
The only way to have two different skins is to have two actual seperate accounts. All the bat file does is change the username, which is not tied to the access token.

I think that the skin I have on my laptop is a default skin, because its not the same as my account skin, is there anyway I can change the default skin on my laptop so it defaults to the skin I want?

Use the original username that generated the token in your bat file. The skin is tied to the account/session/name combination. tl;dr - Get two accounts.

to buy another account cost's 30 $, I cant spend that kind of money right now, id rather try do this and learn something along the way.
